# Permission denied after compilation with help of makefile

Tags: c, linux, makefile, permission-denied

I get this when I try to run my programm :
bash: ./supermarket: Permission denied

The executable files appear as binary files with read & write permissions to user but no execute permission

This is the code of my makefile can u figure out what is wrong?

```
OBJS    = supermarket.o cashier.o customer.o 
SOURCE  = supermarket.c cashier.c customer.c 
HEADER  = struct.h
OUT     = supermarket cashier customer
CC  = gcc
FLAGS   = -lrt -g -c 

#LIBS   = -lm
# -g option enables debugging mode 
# -c flag generates object code for separate files
# -lm math library
# -lrt semaphores

all: supermarket cashier customer

supermarket: supermarket.c
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) supermarket.c -o supermarket 

cashier: cashier.c
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) cashier.c -o cashier 

customer: customer.c
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) customer.c -o customer

# clean house
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(OUT)
# do a bit of accounting
count:
    wc $(SOURCE) $(HEADER)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
FLAGS   = -lrt -g -c
```

Specifically, the `-c` flag. It stops compilation at the object stage, so your `supermarket`, `cashier`, and `customer` "executables" are actually object files without their usual extension.

Comment: I dont understand, so we should not use -c extension while creating object files?

Comment: @UnderDog No, you should use -c when creating object files, the OP here wants the final executables, not an object file.

Answer (score 1):

You are compiling and creating object files, not executable files.  -c option to gcc tells it to not invoke the linker.
I think [this](http://mrbook.org/tutorials/make/) is a good simplest make tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

`compile *.c program`; then `gcc -o` to link and create an executable.

Or `gcc -o ___ -c ____.c` to do it all in one command.