# Getting "Permission denied" when running this code

Tags: c, linux

I am writing a basic C program and using PuTTY to execute this program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct{
        unsigned int *r;
}Image;
int main()
{
    printf("yes\n");
    unsigned int a = 7;
    Image *image;
    image = malloc(sizeof(Image));
    image->r[0] = a;
    printf("r[0] =");
    printf("%d\n",image->r[0]);
    free(image);
    return 0;
}
```

I executed it but I am getting an error.

```
$ gcc -c test.c -o test -Wall -std=c11
$ ./test
./test: Permission denied.
```

I am new to pointers and other stuff. So, I don't know what to do next

Comment: This has nothing to do with pointers, or even your C code for that matter. The file `test` doesn't have execute permissions. Run `chmod u+x ./test` in the shell to give yourself execute permissions.

Comment: Even if you run your program it invokes undefined behaviour as `r` does not reference valid memory location.

Comment: Why are you compiling with -c?

Comment: `image->r[0] = a;` I think you meant `image->r = &a;`

Comment: Tried that. did not work

Comment: @Irelia hah! I didn't notice that! Make an answer.

Comment: There is already a command in the unix/Linux super basic set of commands named `test`. Eliminate a whole class of problems from debugging your code or failed system scripts and use another name, `myTest` etc. Good luck.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Permission denied after compilation with help of makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8933333/permission-denied-after-compilation-with-help-of-makefile)